# Weights decay on evaluation step - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

My weights are defined as

```
weights = {
        'W_conv1': tf.get_variable('W_conv1', shape=[...], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)),
        'W_conv2': tf.get_variable('W_conv2', shape=[...], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)),
        'W_conv3': tf.get_variable('W_conv3', shape=[...], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)),
        ...
}

# conv2d network
...
```

I want to use the weights decay so I add, for example, the argument

```
regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer(0.0005)
```

to the `tf.get_variable`. Now I'm wondering if during the evaluation phase this is still correct or maybe I have to set the regularizer factor to 0.

There is also another argument `trainable`. The documentation says `If True also add the variable to the graph collection GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES.` which is not clear to me. Should I use it?

Can someone explain to me if the weights decay effects in a sort of wrong way the evaluation step? How can I solve in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight decay is used during the weight update step during training in back-propagation. There is no such weight update during evaluation, so it doesn't have any effect during evaluation. As for the argument trainable I think this excerpt from the official doc is quite concise

> When building a machine learning model it is often convenient to
>   distinguish between variables holding the trainable model parameters
>   and other variables such as a global step variable used to count
>   training steps. To make this easier, the variable constructor supports
>   a trainable= parameter. If True, the new variable is also added
>   to the graph collection GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES. The convenience
>   function trainable_variables() returns the contents of this
>   collection. The various Optimizer classes use this collection as the
>   default list of variables to optimize.

So you can add it for convenience but its not mandatory.